# ¿Cómo solucionar problema de visualización de proyecto en Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Realicé la instalación de laravel en mi computadora:

[Instrucciones para instalar Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7#server-requirements)

De los cuales seguí los pasos que me indicaban para la instalación de laravel, pero para ello primero instale composer, que lo descargue desde la página oficial de composer

[Instalación de composer](https://getcomposer.org/download/)

Que realice la instalación del composer, tengo instalado en mi computadora el software Visual Studio Code, una vez instalado composer instalé Laravel pero para ello desde mi PC, me fui al disco C: y dentro de la carpeta C:\xampps\htdocs desde la barra de mi pc entre al CMD digitando cmd, y desde la ventana de comandos que instale Laravel con este comando composer global require laravel/installer, luego de aquello cree un nuevo proyecto de laravel desde la misma ventana de comandos así de esta manera: laravel new proyectolavarel.
Una vez que se creó el proyecto de laravel, al ejecutar el visual Studio Code y del menú que seleccione Abrir (File); y abrir carpeta (Open Folder); del disco C:\xampps\htdocs\proyectolavarel (que escogí) y ahora desde el mismo editor "Visual Studio Code" al seleccionar View (Vista) y del menú Terminal, compile el proyecto de laravel de esta manera desde el terminal:

php artisan serve (que luego me aparece una ruta para poner en la barra de dirección de navegación del navegador sea esta Google Chrome, Mozilla, Opera); pero al tratar de abrir desde el navegador no abre el proyecto, o no se visualiza la pantalla de laravel, necesito saber, ¿Qué puedo hacer?; Qué no se visualiza el proyecto; adjunto pantalla del visual Studio Code.

[image: Pantalla del Visual Studio Code]

Comment: ¿Lograste solucionarlo? De ser ese el caso, agrega lo que hiciste y marca la respuesta como aceptada. Colaborarías con la buena salud del sitio. Saludos :D

Answer (score 0):

Estas confundiendo un par de cosas:

- De acuerdo a lo que mencionas, instalas una copia de Laravel desde la terminal en la ruta: `C:/xampp/htdocs`

Con lo anterior, estas generando un proyecto web dentro de tu servidor local, con lo cual tu proceder debe ser el siguiente para poder abrirlo en tu navegador:

1. Abre `XAMPP Control Panel`

   - click en `start` a los servicios de `MySQL` y `Apache`
   - Abre tu navegador y en la zona de URL, escribes lo siguiente:

---

```
localhost/miproyecto/public
```

2. Puedes no hacer uso de XAMPP directamente para ejecutar tu proyecto de Laravel; haciendo lo siguiente

Dentro de la carpeta raíz de tu proyecto (esta instalación la puedes hacer en otra ubicación), abre la terminal o CMD y ejecutas el siguiente comando:

```
php artisan serve
```

Posterior, ya desde el navegador puedes acceder a tu proyecto con una URL como esta

```
localhost/miproyecto
```

Sobre el comando `php artisan serve`, que podemos consultar aquí [servidor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/installation#installing-laravel)

Dice:

> Si tienes PHP instalado localmente y te gustaría usar el servidor de desarrollo incorporado para servir tu aplicación, puedes usar el comando `Arisan serve`. Este comando ejecutará un servidor de desarrollo en `http://localhost:8000`

Como último punto deberías leer sobre Homestead, que es un *box de Vagrant* pre hecho para establecer un ambiente de desarrollo para trabajar en Laravel, [aquí mas info.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/homestead)

Comment: Estimado buenos día, te saludo desde Ecuador soy el Lcdo. José Fernando Frugone Jaramillo hice correr el xampp anteriormente el Apache y el mysql compile las librerías *.css *.js anteriorme desde el terminal de visual studio code npm run dev (ya que esta instalado el lavarel mix) cono la instale primeramente instalando node.js a mi computadora y luego desde el terminal de visual studio puse npm install para instalar lavarel mix, compile las librerias *.css y *.js cin el comando o instruccion npm run dev; y al ejecutar php artisan serve con direcc ip en navegador no muestra.

Comment: Solo ejecuta `php artisan serve` en la consola. y en el navegador puede probar con `localhost:8000` o `localhost/nombreproyecto`

Comment: Eso depende si lo quiere ejecutar así o desde xampp o lo que sea que use, además eso también lo incluí en mi respuesta